How fix the issue so I am able to see boolean text in Solid and Material because all of the modifiers was already applied including boolean? Pls help?
I can see engraved (boolean) "barbie" text on heart necklace in wireframe but not solid and material view in Blender 4.2.1.



Do you hide the "Barbie" object after the boolean operation ? Because it might be this object that is still visible.

Edit the object, select all the faces inside the Barbie text, then extrude.
